# what is the location option when creating new bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I' working with `minio` and `python`.
I looked on the API of creating new bucket:

https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html#make_bucket

I can't understand what is the meaning of `location`?

The description in the API (`Region in which the bucket will be created.`) doesn't tell me much.

How can I use it? Is it a sub folder?

What is the right way to use the location value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a sub folder.

When you create a bucket, you choose its name and the AWS Region to create it in. After you create a bucket, you can't change its name or Region.

Also, what you might find interesting, if you're using the AWS Console, that is shows all your buckets, in all regions, which might imply that `S3` is a global service.

However, buckets exist in a specific region and you need to specify that region when you create a bucket.

Therefore, in `minio`, by `location`, they mean where you want to have your S3 backet end-point located. [Full list of S3 service end-points is here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html)

So, basically, by setting `location` you get to choose where to "place" your bucket.

Comment: If I run the minio on private network, does the location (region) means the server (node) I want to create the bucket on ?

Comment: You might say that. By the way, the `region` argument is optional, so you can leave it out.